# Upload models to BIM360 Design, not BIM360 Docs

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

I'm able to successfully batch upload Revit models to BIM360 Documents (and version them, as well).  However, my main goal is to be able to batch upload models to BIM360 Design as our day-to-day (pre-published) design models.

It appears that instead of using type `items:autodesk.bim360:File` that I should be using `items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel`.  However, I keep getting "The client_id is not whitelisted for schema items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel."  Is there a way to provision my app to access that?

As a user, I have admin rights to BIM360 Docs, so I don't think it's an individual rights issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible for you to upload “cloud” models with a 
Forge app. It can only be done with a Revit Addin today.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Forge DM API doesn't support enabling C4R model currently. However, you can do that with Revit API with Revit desktop, see here for the details: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/11/initiating-bim360-collaboration-and-linking.html#2

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I was hoping that there was some way to get rights to post C4R items.  I looked through Jeremy's blog, and unfortunately the workaround won't work for my situation.  We have a number of models that are developed outside of the BIM360 environment that rely heavily on worksharing, and if we have to upload a model without worksharing first (and then convert once there) we'll lose a lot of work.  

I really appreciate the response and help, though!